# Having trouble getting last row from SQLite database

Tags: c#, .net, sql, winforms, sqlite

I am new to SQLite and am trying to read the last very last row from the SQLite database file and failing massively.

I can successfully establish a connection and get the rows but I have no idea how to get the data from the row(s).

I have a Table, called "Mine", like:

```
****************************************
id | name | age | time  | task
0  | tommy| 23  | [time]| went to shops
****************************************
```

I am trying to get the data from the last row of task column, which is of type String.

But:

1. I don't know how to read the data from a row into a C# String, and;
2. I don't know how to structure the select statement so that it only returns that single value from the very last row.

Below is what I have already, which is mostly from a tutorial I found online (which I can't find again yet):

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private SQLiteConnection sql_con;
        private SQLiteCommand sql_cmd;
        private SQLiteDataAdapter DB;
        private DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        private DataTable DT = new DataTable();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SetConnection()
        {
            string databasePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\MyApp\database.db";
            sql_con = new SQLiteConnection
                ("Data Source=" + databasePath + ";Version=3;");
        }

        private void ExecuteQuery(string txtQuery)
        {
            SetConnection();
            sql_con.Open();
            sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
            sql_cmd.CommandText = txtQuery;
            sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sql_con.Close();
        }

        private void LoadData()
        {
            bool gotRow = false;
            try
            {
                SetConnection();
                sql_con.Open();
                sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
                string CommandText = "select task from Mine";
                DB = new SQLiteDataAdapter(CommandText, sql_con);
                DS.Reset();
                DB.Fill(DS);
                DT = DS.Tables[0];

                foreach (DataRow row in DT.Rows)
                {
                    gotRow = true;
                }

                if (gotRow)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(row.ToString());
                    gotRow = false;
                }

                sql_con.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadData();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the data from the very last row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your query to select last `task` ordered by `id` descending:

```
select task
from Mine
order by id desc
limit 1
```

then in your method should look like this::

```
private void LoadData()
{
    try
    {
        SetConnection();
        sql_con.Open();
        sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
        string commandText = "select task from Mine order by id desc limit 1";

        sql_cmd.CommandText = commandText;
        var lsattask = sql_cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        MessageBox.Show(lsattask);

        sql_con.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    }
}
```

`ExecuteScalar` returns result from first row in first column and because we ordered the data by `id` first row is the last one inserted.

Comment: `desc` is a shortcut for `descending` and means to order `id` from highest value to lowest :)

Comment: thanks! For some reason I thought desc meant "description", hence the slight confusion :P lol